# JETPACK COMPOSE "Cannot find parameter with this name: contentAlignment"

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

Am i missing an import or something? Why is this basic function giving me errors all of a sudden

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you didn't miss anything.

You need only to add your **content** parameter, and your alignment parameter would be normal.

Example:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier,
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart,
            content = {}
            )
```

Comment: Why did they make it this unintuitive? How come the IDE doesn't even suggest this. Thanks though, @mustafakhaled

Answer (score 1):

I have also something to add . After what you have typed just open the semicolons and the error goes away , like i mentioned below

```
Box(modifier = Modifier,
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart
            ){
// Semicolon opening 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because exists a [`Box`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#Box(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier)) constructor with no content as in your example code:

```
@Composable
fun Box(modifier: Modifier): Unit
```

The `contentAlignment` doesn't exist in this constructor.

You can use [the constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#Box(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)) with the `contentAlignment` parameter and in this case you have to pass also the `content` parameter:

```
@Composable
inline fun Box(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentAlignment: Alignment = Alignment.TopStart,
    propagateMinConstraints: Boolean = false,
    content: @Composable @ExtensionFunctionType BoxScope.() -> Unit
): Unit
```

For example:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier,
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
){
    //content
}
```